# Kubernetes CronJob Not Correctly Using Docker Secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a Kubernetes cluster that I am trying to set up a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) on.  I have the CronJob set up in the `default` namespace, with the image pull secret I want to use set up in the `default` namespace as well.  I set the `imagePullSecrets` in the `CronJob` to reference the secret I use to pull images from my private docker registry, I can verify this secret is valid because I have deployments in the same cluster and namespace that use this secret to successfully pull docker images.  However, when the `CronJob` pod starts, I see the following error:

```
no basic auth credentials
```

I understand this happens when the pod doesn't have credentials to pull the image from the docker registry.  But I am using the same secret for my deployments in the same namespace and they successfully pull down the image.  Is there a difference in the configuration of using `imagePullSecrets` between deployments and cronjobs?

Server Version: v1.9.3

CronJob config:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: my-cronjob
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  schedule: 30 13 * * *
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: my-secret
          containers:
          - image: my-image
            name: my-cronjob
            command:
            - my-command
            args:
            - my-args
```

Comment: Could you provide configuration for your CronJob?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev I added it to the question, good idea, thanks!

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: no, I did not, though I am not actively working on it anymore

Answer (score -1):

yaml it's ok, try to verify that credential, image name and tag of your  it's ok (yourusername/privateimage:version). You could run a pod with the same image of cronJob and verify that's running .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).